# aws code deploy can't access bash variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have a script I'm run as root user in a BeforeInstall hook, I'm trying to access some variables I have placed into the `/root/.bashrc`, but I've been unable to get the variable contents to display?

Is there something I'm missing from being able to access the variable?

```
/root/.bashrc
...
export FOO="bar"
...
```

deployment_script run as `root` in a BeforeInstall hook

```
#!/bin/bash

echo `whoami` // prints root
...
echo $FOO  // prints nothing
...
MY_VAR=`echo $FOO`
echo $MY_VAR // prints nothing
...
```

I've tried sourcing the `/root/.bashrc`, I've tried placing the variables in the `/root/.profile`,  I can't eval anything that includes them b/c it still comes up empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading `/root/.bashrc` script explicitly in your `deployment_script`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Your deployment script

. "/root/.bashrc"
whoami
echo $FOO
# ...
```

Comment: try to check permissions maybe?

Comment: any error?  you can change `.` to `source` command to execute desired file in deployment script context

Comment: I found the issue.  at the top of /root/.bashrc are these two lines `# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`